# ionCube PHP module gets error

Tags: php, ioncube, php-extension

i have uploaded my site on a sharing host.i use ionCube PHP in my site.
the index page of site gives this error:

" index.php requires the ionCube PHP Loader ioncube_loader_lin_5.2.so to be installed by the site administrator. "

i asked the server support team and the said ionCube is installed on server.

if so why cause above error??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check your php.ini, is there something like `zend_extension=ioncube_loader_lin_5.2.so`?
if not add in the path to ioncube_loader_lin_5.2.so, restart apache

- my ioncube is ages, hopefully is still using `zend_extension=ioncube_loader_lin_5.2.so` to load the module into php

Comment: it is on a sharing host.have can i check php.ini and change its content?

Comment: in that case, have to ask the server support team who has the administrator right for file write to check for u

Comment: @hd - ioncube message from my server `No loader is installed` for `ionCube PHP Loader v3.1.32`

Comment: thanks.i override php.ini with custom php.ini and it is ok now.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the server has a different version of ionCube. Look at your phpinfo to verify that it is installed and the version is correct.

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Comment: what is get this: This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine:
Zend Engine v2.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
    with the ionCube PHP Loader v3.3.20, Copyright (c) 2002-2010, by ionCube Ltd., and
    with Zend Optimizer v3.3.9, Copyright (c) 1998-2009, by Zend Technologies

Comment: So it is ionCube loader V3.3.20. The latest version for Linux is version 4.0.1 according to http://www.ioncube.com/loaders.php What version of ionCube are you encoding the files with before you upload them?

Comment: I have also found the ionCube support to be good. Try asking them for help via http://support.ioncube.com/index.php?department=3

Answer (score 2):

Seems like some misconfiguration on your host.

`phpinfo()` should reveal something like this:

```
This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine:
Zend Engine v2.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2007 Zend Technologies
    with eAccelerator v0.9.5.1, Copyright (c) 2004-2006 eAccelerator, by eAccelerator
    with the ionCube PHP Loader v3.1.31, Copyright (c) 2002-2007, by ionCube Ltd.
    with Suhosin v0.9.18, Copyright (c) 2002-2006, by Hardened-PHP Project
```