# I installed ionCube but it is not working yet

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx, ioncube

I have a Ubuntu server 22.04 and I have installed PHP 8.1.2 fpm, MySQL 8, and nginx

After I installed WordPress and active a new theme (Harika) then I get this error:

[image]

Then I installed the ionCube from the ionCube wizard and now it is installed on my server:

[image]

But it is not working and when I browse my wordpress website I get 500 error

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please make sure IonCube module is installed and enabled in your web server(Nginx, Apache,...), and if it is not fixed, see your web server logs for more details.
refer to the links below:

[how-to-install-ioncube-loader-on-ubuntu](https://www.cloudbooklet.com/how-to-install-ioncube-loader-on-ubuntu/)

[similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4153480/ioncube-php-module-gets-error)

Comment: Yes, I installed IonCube completely and when I run PHP - v, it says the ionCube is installed and when I run ionCube Wizard it says "The ionCube Loader version 12.0.5 for PHP 8.1 is installed and encoded files should run successfully." but it is not working

Comment: did you enable it on your web server?

Comment: I added "zend_extension = /usr/lib/php/20210902/ioncube_loader_lin_8.1.so" on php.ini and then restart Nginx and php8.1-fpm.  is it enough?

Comment: I checked the Nginx error log:  `[2023/01/04 13:16:16 [error] 3139740#3139740: *59 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  The file /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/themes/harika/functions.php encoded as type [1/72] cannot be in Unknown on line 0" while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.52.42, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock:", host: "192.168.57.115"`